# Main activity sometimes created a second time

Tags: android

My app has a main activity and other activities that are started from it.

Usually, launching the app starts the main activity and then if I try to launch the app again from the home screen, the app is just brought back to the foreground, showing whatever activity was at the top of the stack.
This is what I want to happen.

Analysing the crash reports from my app I can see that in some cases the main activity is started a second time. I can't make this happen on my test device/emulator and I don't know exactly what the users are doing to trigger the issue.

Here's the (anonymised) log:

```
09/11/2017 23:49:29.979: Information: App starting
09/11/2017 23:49:30.313: Information: Activity OnCreate (launching:True): MainActivity
09/11/2017 23:49:30.321: Information: Main activity launch intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10600000 cmp=com.company.appname/md50e6758159625f2df0d9d3f1df35dbb47.MainActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } bnds=[544,189][797,486] (has extras) }
09/11/2017 23:49:38.152: Information: Activity OnCreate (launching:True): SecondActivity
09/11/2017 23:49:53.815: Information: App going to background
09/11/2017 23:51:07.257: Information: Activity OnCreate (launching:True): MainActivity
09/11/2017 23:51:07.268: Information: Main activity launch intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10600000 cmp=com.company.appname/md50e6758159625f2df0d9d3f1df35dbb47.MainActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } bnds=[544,189][797,486] (has extras) }
09/11/2017 23:51:07.380: Information: App going to foreground
09/11/2017 23:51:10.018: Information: Activity OnCreate (launching:True): ThirdActivity
09/11/2017 23:51:12.801: Information: Activity OnDestroy (finishing:True): ThirdActivity
09/11/2017 23:51:13.412: Information: Activity OnCreate (launching:True): SecondActivity
```

What can cause this behaviour?

I'd like to point out that the app process doesn't get killed, so it's not simply the app getting started again after being terminated due to memory pressure.

Comment: Your code may be useful for us to really understand what's going on

Comment: did you try putting launchmode:single in your manifest file?

Comment: @Sapher It's a big app and I'm not allowed to share the code.

Comment: @Prachi One of those launchmodes might help but I'd like to understand first why Android is trying to create a new instance.

Comment: @Zmaster You can hide your business logic :).

Answer (score 0):

Try launch mode, singleTop for your activity in the manifest.
It might solve your problem.

You can also check this reference for better understanding.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes

Comment: That wouldn't work if there are other activities at the top of the task. SingleTask would probably be a better choice, but I'd like to understand why Android tries to create again the activity instead of bringing the app to the foreground like it usually does.

Comment: @Zmaster singleTask or singleTop thats on your usage. But go through the link again.May be try reading complete page. You will get your answer for the multiple instance of activity. Thanks.